# roswtf finds error, flag do not match

Tags: ros, manifest.xml, roswtf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I'm using fuerte with Ubuntu 11.10 installed, I use roswtf to examine your ROS setup. I encounter a problem.
I type:

```
dong@dong-Inspiron-N5110:/opt/ros/fuerte/share/roscpp$ roswtf
```

and

```
Loaded plugin tf.tfwtf
Package: roscpp
================================================================================
Static checks summary:

Found 1 error(s).

ERROR The following packages have rpath issues in manifest.xml:
 * roscpp: found flag "-L/opt/ros/fuerte/lib", but no matching "-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ros/fuerte/lib"

================================================================================

ROS Master does not appear to be running.
Online graph checks will not be run.
ROS_MASTER_URI is [http://localhost:11311]
```

What's wrong with the setup?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39441/roswtf-finds-error,-flag-do-not-match/) by [dragonfly90](https://answers.ros.org/users/2860/dragonfly90/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That roscpp error is a known problem. You can ignore it.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1